# Trying to run puppet yield "Error: Could not find class"

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

Firstly, to be honest I'm pretty new to Puppet world. I'm trying to build a puppet script for my server.

here how my puppet structure look like this

```
.
|-- environments
|   `-- example_env
|       |-- manifests
|       |-- modules
|       `-- README.environment
|-- manifests
|   |-- node.pp
|   `-- site.pp
|-- modules
|   |-- nginx
|   |   `-- manifests
|   |       `-- nginx.pp
|   |-- sudoers
|   |   |-- files
|   |   |   `-- sudoers
|   |   `-- manifests
|   |       `-- sudoers.pp
|   `-- users
|       `-- manifests
|           `-- users.pp
|-- puppet.conf
`-- templates
```

here how my `node.pp` and `site.pp` look like this.

```
# /etc/puppet/manifests/node.pp
node werain {
  include sudoers
}
```

and

```
 # etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
 import 'node.pp'
```

and finally my `sudoers.pp` file look like this.

```
# /etc/puppet/modules/sudoers/manifests/sudoers.pp
class sudoers {
  file { '/etc/sudoers':
    mode: '0400',
    source: 'puppet:///modules/sudoers/sudoers',
    owner: 'root',
    group: 'root'
  }
}
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong.

I'm running the `puppet` command like this.

```
puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules/
```

my `puppet` version is  `3.8.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you build a module you need to have an `init.pp` file in the manifests directory.

Rename to look like this:

```
# /etc/puppet/modules/sudoers/manifests/init.pp
class sudoers {
  file { '/etc/sudoers':
    mode: '0400',
    source: 'puppet:///modules/sudoers/sudoers',
    owner: 'root',
    group: 'root'
  }
}
```